# textbox can't retain value on submit

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, textbox, submit

First, note that I am developping in french so some terms are in french, but elements name are in english. If any questions, feel free to ask.

I'm working on an ASP web page with vb.net and I have a form with 4 textbox. The user have the choice to log in with his number  or by entering his Last name , First name  and birthday. In the beginning, when I clicked on my submit button everything worked fine but now, when I enter text in my textbox, when clicking on submit all my textbox values are empty. When validating my form, it is always returning false.

Here is the code-behind. If you need other elements of my code such as: javascript code, html code or anything, feel free to ask. This problem drives me crazy for the last days and I read a lot of documentation on stackoverflow and other forums with no success...

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class WebForm1
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected SqlCon_PAIE As New SqlConnection
Protected SqlCon_Gamsco As New SqlConnection
Public Event LostFocus As EventHandler

Private Sub Get_Value_GAMSCO()
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim DatS As New DataSet
    Dim SQLadap As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter

    SqlCon_Gamsco.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("String_Connection_Gamsco").ConnectionString

    strSQL = " SELECT TOP 2 * " & _
                " FROM [GAMSCO].[RAPPORTS]"

    SQLadap = New SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, SqlCon_Gamsco)
    SQLadap.Fill(DatS, "Recherche")

    SqlCon_Gamsco.Dispose()
End Sub

Protected Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click
    Dim MatriculeComplete As Boolean = False
    Dim infosComplete As Boolean = False
    If ((Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtNumber.Text)) Or (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLastName.Text) And Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFirstName.Text) And Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(hfDateNaisVal.Value()))) Then
        LblWarning.Text = ""

        'Si le matricule n'est pas vide 
        If (hfMatricule.Value().Equals("true")) Then
            MatriculeComplete = True
        End If

        'Si les infos sont complètes
        If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtLastName.Text) And Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFirstName.Text) And Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(hfDateNaisVal.Value())) Then
            If (hfDateNais.Value().Equals("true")) Then
                infosComplete = True
            End If
        End If
    End If
    If (MatriculeComplete = False And infosComplete = False) Then
        LblWarning.Text = "Le matricule ou les informations personnelles sont manquantes ou incomplètes"
    ElseIf (MatriculeComplete = True) Then
        rechercher_employe_matricule(txtNumber.Text)
    ElseIf (infosComplete = True) Then
        rechercher_employe_infos(txtFirstName.Text, txtLastName.Text, hfDateNaisVal.Value())
    End If
    reset_champs()
End Sub

Protected Sub reset_champs()
    txtNumber.Text = ""
    hfMatricule.Value() = ""
    hfDateNaisVal.Value() = ""
    hfDateNais.Value() = ""
    txtLastName.Text = ""
    txtFirstName.Text = ""
End Sub
Private Sub rechercher_employe_infos(prenom As String, nom As String, dateNais As String)
    'Dim dateParts As String() = dateNais.Split("-")
    'Dim dateArrange As String = dateParts(2) + "-" + dateParts(1) + "-" + dateParts(0)
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim DatS As New DataSet
    Dim SQLadap As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter

    SqlCon_PAIE.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("String_Connection_Paie").ConnectionString

    strSQL = " SELECT MATR, upper(left(NOM,1)) + lower(right(NOM,len(NOM)-1)) AS 'NOM', upper(left(PRNOM,1)) + lower(right(PRNOM,len(PRNOM)-1)) as 'PRENOM', DATE_NAIS" & _
                    " FROM PAI_DOS" & _
                    " WHERE (NOM like '%" & nom & "') AND (PRNOM like '%" & prenom & "') AND (DATE_NAIS like (convert(datetime,'" & dateNais & "')))"

    SQLadap = New SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, SqlCon_PAIE)
    SQLadap.Fill(DatS, "Recherche")


    If DatS.Tables("Recherche").Rows.Count > 0 Then
        With DatS.Tables("Recherche").Rows(0)
            'Response.Redirect("formulaire.aspx?Mat=" & Server.UrlEncode(.Item(0)))
        End With
    Else
        LblWarning.Text = "L'employé " + prenom + " " + nom + " " + dateNais + " n'existe pas dans la base de données"
    End If
    SqlCon_PAIE.Dispose()
End Sub
Private Sub rechercher_employe_matricule(matricule As String)
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim DatS As New DataSet
    Dim SQLadap As SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter

    SqlCon_PAIE.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("String_Connection_Paie").ConnectionString

    strSQL = " SELECT MATR" & _
                    " FROM PAI_DOS" & _
                    " WHERE (MATR like '%" & matricule & "')"

    SQLadap = New SqlDataAdapter(strSQL, SqlCon_PAIE)
    SQLadap.Fill(DatS, "Recherche")


    If DatS.Tables("Recherche").Rows.Count > 0 Then
        With DatS.Tables("Recherche").Rows(0)
            'Response.Redirect("formulaire.aspx?Mat=" & Server.UrlEncode(.Item(0)))
        End With
    Else
        LblWarning.Text = "Le matricule " + matricule + " n'existe pas dans la base de données"
    End If
    SqlCon_PAIE.Dispose()
End Sub

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        txtNumber.Text = txtNumber.Text
    End If
End Sub

'Protected Sub txtMatricule_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtMatricule.TextChanged
'    txtMatricule.Text = txtMatricule.Text
'    MsgBox(txtMatricule.Text)
'End Sub
End Class
```

And the aspx page

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="accueil.aspx.vb" Inherits="Gamsco_Web.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Gamsco - Authentification</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles\Site.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js">    </script>

</head>
<body style="text-align:center;">
<h1 class="header">Rapport d&#39;accident ou d&#39;événement dangereux</h1>
<div class="page">
    <div class="global">
        <div class="subtitle">Veuillez saisir le matricule ou nom, prénom et date de naissance du blessé</div>
        <form id="form1" runat="server" >
            <table style="width: 65%; height: 250px; ">
                <tr>
                    <td class="style5">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblMatricule" runat="server" Text="Matricule:">   </asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="style6">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtNumber" runat="server" Width="188px" MaxLength="9" ></asp:TextBox> 
                    </td>
                    <td class="style7"> 
                        <div id="errMatr" class="err"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="style2">
                    </td>
                    <td class="style1">
                        <strong style="text-align: justify">ou</strong>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfMatricule" runat="server" />
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfDateNais" runat="server" />
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="hfDateNaisVal" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="style2">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblNom" runat="server" Text="Nom:"></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                    <td class="style1">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" width="191px" ></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td class="style7"> 
                        <div id="errNom" class="err"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="style2">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblPrenom" runat="server" Text="Prenom:"></asp:Label>
                     </td>
                    <td class="style1">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" width="191px"></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                    <td class="style7"> 
                        <div id="errPrenom" class="err"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="style3">
                        <asp:Label ID="lblDateNaissance" runat="server" Text="Date de naissance:"></asp:Label>
                    </td>

                    <td class="style4">
                        <input id="datepicker" class="calendar" placeholder="JJ-MM-AAAA" type="text" 
                            maxlength="10" />
                   </td>
                   <td class="style7"> 
                        <div id="errDateNais" class="err"></div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <asp:button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Continuer"></asp:button>
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="LblWarning" runat="server" ForeColor="Red"></asp:Label>
        </form>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="footer">test</div>
<script src="ScriptApp/App.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/date-fr-CA.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you copy the .aspx page as well?

Comment: voila! the aspx page is here

Comment: Do you want to retain the TextBox values after the `recherche`*-methods? If you do, you should remove the `reset_champs()`-call at the end of the submit method.

Comment: No. Basically When clicking on the button I'm verifying that my number is not empty or that first name and last name and birthday are filled. If first or second option is filled, I'm calling the "recherche" (in english its searching; one is with number other is with first name, last name and birthday) depending which part is completly filled. The reset_champs() is executed to erase hidden field and textboux value after the validations. Even when I comment this line, I have the same problem.

Comment: have you got viewstate enabled?

Comment: I got nothing in my code about viewstate enable. Can develop more about that? I think I know what you want to say.

Comment: @Jean-MichelPlourde , can you check this link to see if this helps. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/81489/ViewState-Control-in-ASP-NET-4-0

Comment: Not related to the question but you should really use SQLParameter. Try type a single quote ' in your text box.

Comment: @Junaid: I visited your link and it completed my knowledge about viewstate mode that I acquired after your previous message. Even in ispostback condition, my txtNumber.text is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that with good debuging you will be able to figure this out.

I would definitely start by removing the javascript, that client side code could absolutely affect your value before they are posted back.

Make everything simple, take out the page.load code, it is doing nothing good for you.

Comment out the if code in the btnSubmit.click and just act as if the value will be there for now since you're just testing.

Overall I don't see why the values wouldn't be there.